# tool to look at history and recommend shortcuts, aliases or script functions

Tags: command-history

Is there any tool which looks at my command history on the command line and does any of the following

- list most commonly typed in commands
- list most commonly typed in sequence of commands(e..g I always cd to this folder and then run these two commands)
- suggest ways to automate it. e.g. suggest aliases or functions that I can paste in my bashrc file to speed up that workflow

Comment: I don't know of any such tool.  [vgrep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_inspection), perhaps? :-).    The first is easy (`history | cut -d' ' -f3- | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn`) unless you have `erasedups` and/or `ignoredups` in $HISTCONTROL.     I suspect that anyone capable of writing the other two would have no need of them because writing aliases or functions wouldn't seem difficult.

Comment: your best bet is to ask yourself "what do i do a lot that i find tedious and/or error-prone?".  and then write a script, function, or alias to automate it and reduce the chance of typos and other human-error.

Answer (score 4):

The `history` and `fc` commands will be a good starting point (see `man bash`, which I used recently to check the command line flags for `fc`). Here is one possible way to address the first of your requirements,

```
fc -nl -${HISTSIZE:-500} | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | awk '$1>1' | tail -n5
```

In my case it outputs this, showing me that I ping Google's endpoint quite a lot, and I seem to have been doing a reasonable amount of work on my `/etc/hosts` file,

```
  8          man bash
  8          ping someHost
  9          ping anotherHost
 11          vi /etc/hosts
 12          ping -c2 8.8.8.8
```